# query problem with linq: Unable to cast object

Tags: linq

This particular query is giving me an error please tell where am I going wrong

```
public IList <BC_FeedbackBy> GetFeedbackList()
        {
            int feedbackId = 0;
            string feedbackName = string.Empty;

            using (brandconnectionsEntities modelObject = new brandconnectionsEntities())
            {
                return (IList<BC_FeedbackBy>)(from s in modelObject.BC_FeedbackBy
                               select new 
                               {

                                  feedbackId =s.FeedbackById ,
                                  feedbackName=s.FeedbackBy  ,
                               })
                  .ToList ();
            }
        }
```

error is

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List
`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System .Int32,System.String]]' to type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[BrandConnectionsPrototype.Models.BC_FeedbackBy]'.
```

Answer (score 3):

`select new` creates instances of a new anonymous type. The query creates a list of these and then you try to cast that to `IList<BC_FeedbackBy>`. Create new instances of `BC_FeedbackBy` in the query instead.

Something like

```
select new BC_FeedbackBy() 
{
   feedbackId =s.FeedbackById ,
   feedbackName=s.FeedbackBy  ,
})
```

Comment: You don't need a constructor for this, the default generated empty one works since you're using object initializers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Doh, you're right. I was thinking about using the constructor, but as I just copied the code from the question I ended up using properties so the default constructor is enough for this. Thanks!